# Find the correct distribution of $X$?

Tags: probability

An urn contains 5 red, 3 orange, and 1 blue ball. Two balls are randomly
selected (without replacement). Let $X$ be the number of orange balls selected.

I would then like to figure out how $X$ is distributed so that I can compute the probabilities of events, find expectation, etc.

My guess is that $X$ is distributed as a hypergeometric distribution. More specifically, I propose that the PDF is given by the following(where $o=3, r=5, b=1, n=2$):

$$
Pr(X=k) = \frac{\binom{o}{k} \binom{r+b}{n-k}}{\binom{r+o+b}{n}} \quad \text{for $0 \leq k \leq 2$}
$$
I assume that the individual balls are equally likely to be selected. I am unsure because there is only one blue ball($b=1$) so the numerator might be incorrect... Of course, there may also be bigger problems in my reasoning.

Is this correct? Is is true that $X \sim HGeom(o, r+b, n)$? Why/why not?

Comment: Your work is correct.

Comment: @MathLover Great! But I think I have confused myself somehow - say that $k=0$ then $\binom{r+b}{n-k} = \binom{r+b}{n}$. If there are 5 red balls and 1 blue ball, this would be incorrect for $n > 2$, right? Because a blue ball cannot ever multiple places, like the red balls

Comment: That's not true. Say $n = 3, k = 0$. You can write the numerator either as ${5 \choose 2} + {5 \choose 3} ~$ or as $~ {6 \choose 3}$. Both are equal.

Comment: @sdsadasdasd  That is $\binom 52\binom 11+\binom 53\binom 10$ via. counting whether the lone blue ball is included among the three non-orange, or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@sdsadasdasd  You have $3$ orange and $6$ non-orange balls.   You are not really concerned about whether the later are red or blue.   You just wish to count how many are orange among the $2$ selected.

The probability for obtaining $k$ from the $3$ orange balls when selecting $2$ from the $9$ balls is$$\mathsf P(X=k)=\dfrac{\dbinom 3k\dbinom 6{2-k}}{\dbinom 92}\,\mathbf 1_{0\leq k\leq 2}$$

Which is indeed a hypergeometric probability mass function.

---

Now, you could extend this to the multivariate case where $Y$ is the count for blue balls. Then $$\mathsf P(X=k, Y=h)=\dfrac{\dbinom 3k\dbinom 1h\dbinom 5{2-k-h}}{\dbinom 92}\mathbf 1_{0\leq h\leq 1~,~ 0\leq k\leq 2-h}$$

Then by the Law of Total Probability $$\mathsf P(X=k)=\mathsf P(X=k, Y=0)+\mathsf P(X=k,Y=1)$$

Which equals the original equation, since, $\dbinom 10\dbinom 5{2-k}+\dbinom 11\dbinom 5{1-k}=\dbinom{6}{2-k}$.